# Как сделать, чтобы при сдвижении шапки менялся ее цвет?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Не могу понять, с помощью чего и как можно реализовать, такую же фишку, как например на этом сайте https://www.justinmind.com , изначально шапка загружается одним цветом, а потом при смещении она его меняет. Как это сделать?

Comment: js меняет div-у style от style="background-color: rgb(64, 210, 210);"   до style="background-color: rgba(64, 210, 210, 0);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью скрипта, который при скролле добавляет/удаляет специальный класс, меняющий внешний вид шапки:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 10) {
    $('header').addClass('fixed');
  }
  else {
    $('header').removeClass('fixed');
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  height: 1000px;
}
header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 0;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
header.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  шапка
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще один вариант jQuery. Плюс небольшая анимация перехода с одного цвета в другой с помощью свойства `transition`.

```js
$(document).scroll(function(e) {
  $(window).scrollTop() > 100 ? $('.nav').addClass('nav__color') : $('.nav').removeClass('nav__color');
});
```

```css
body {height: 2000px;}

.nav {
  position: fixed; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 50px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  transition: background 2s;
}

.nav__color {background: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav"></div>
```